# What is execution model for *args in function call?

Tags: python, function

I need to pass huge `list`/`tuple` to function through `*args`.

```
def f(*args):  # defined in foreign module
    pass

arguments = tuple(range(10000))
f(*arguments)
```

And I wonder what happens at function call.

Does it handle `arguments` similar to any positional variable: save it and access on-demand during body execution? Or does it iterate through `arguments` even before body execution, extending positional arguments? Or is it something else?

Comment: Since `arguments` is a list, but `args` is a tuple, yes, iteration *has* to take place. Not that making `arguments` a tuple here would help.

Comment: You could try testing that by writing a custom object that tells you when it's being iterated over.

Comment: So even if `arguments` is a tuple, this iteration happens anyway?

Comment: @Ormazd yes. The same principle happens with keyword arguments, a new `dict` is created.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why? :)

Comment: @Ormazd I do not know the reasoning behind this design decision. Others may know.

Comment: @Ormazd: why *not*? The call must work for *any function*, including those that don't pack arbitrary arguments into a tuple or dict with `*` and `**`. And since a `dict` is *mutable*, you really don't want to share such an object. That'd lead to very weird and hard to debug errors, as one side or the other tries to edit that dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dont know why or why not. I assumed there could be extra logic for *args and **kwargs or it could be "syntax sugar" for regular positional and keyword arguments. Thx for answer. Add: yes, with mutable dict it is more weird =)

Comment: Changed `list` to `tuple` in question. Since `list` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that Python, being a dynamic language, does not know that `f` takes variable arguments at the time the call is interpreted. So it could only handle that after the fact, so you would likely have to build a lot of extra logic. Logic that simply doesn’t exist (yet) because there is not really a need to optimize this further. In practice, you don’t really pass hundreds of arguments to a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `*arguments` call syntax *has* to iterate over the `arguments` iterable, for two reasons:

- You are passing in a list, but the `*args` variable-size argument in the function is a tuple. So elements will have to be copied here.
- The call syntax has to be usable for *any* function, where you may have actual positional arguments instead of, or in addition to, a `*varargs` variable.

  For example, if the function signature was `def f(foo, *args):`, then the first element would have to be passed in separately.

  In principle, CPython could optimise for the case where all values of a *tuple* used in a call with `function(*tupleargs)` end up in a `*varargs` argument, and re-use that tuple. However, this is actually not all *that* common and no-one has done this.

Note that for the `**kwargs` call syntax, the added challenge of *mutability* makes sharing the object used a really bad idea; you *have* to create a copy of the dict used because otherwise the function *or* the caller could mutate that dictionary with the changes reflected in the other reference.

Answer (score 12):

A simple test using a generator:

```
def gen():
    print('Yielding 1')
    yield 1
    print('Yielding 2')
    yield 2
    print('Yielding 3')
    yield 3


arguments = gen()
def f(*args):
    pass

f(*arguments)
# Yielding 1
# Yielding 2
# Yielding 3
```

As you can see from the output, passing `*arguments` will actually unpack the whole iterable, since technically, you are telling Python to pass the iterable as individual arguments using the `*arguments` syntax. It does not matter that the function definition also uses `*args` which makes Python pack the arguments back into a tuple again.

So yeah, you are unpacking the list only to pack it again here. You can avoid this by just passing the list directly.

Comment: There is a *possibility* to not iterate over a *tuple* when used in the call (e.g. `*(1, 2, 3)`) because the values end up in the `*args` variable in the function, but Python makes no such optimisation.